# Connect to a host that doesn't answer to ping

Tags: python, email, smtp, nmap

I am trying to connect to a smtp port to automatically send emails through it. The problem is that when trying to connect to it with python smtplib it gives an error that it can't connect to the host. When trying to run nmap with the command

```
 nmap -T4 -p 25,587,465
```

I get the following output:

```
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.12 seconds
```

When I add the -Pn option I get the following output:

```
Host is up.

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp  filtered smtp
465/tcp filtered smtps
587/tcp filtered submission
```

The python script that I have used is:

```py
import smtplib, ssl
port = 465
password = "password"
email = "my@mail"
hostname = "hostname"
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(hostname, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(email, password)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I am running the code on a Windows 10 machine and using Python 3.7.5.

Is there any way for me to connect to one of the email ports and send emails through it through python or c/c++?

Comment: I wouldn't expect smtplib to try pinging, since many servers block it.

Comment: So you've found that the server has open ports on 25, 465 and 587, which are probably being listened on by an SMTP server. Now you should investigate the cause of the actual error you've encountered. e.g. tell us what it is, show us your code, read server error logs

Comment: I have added the code and the error it gives me to the question. Looking it into the internet did not yield me any useful results.

Comment: Now the server logs

Comment: I don't have access to the server, just the email and password.